# Can the standard library to_string function work for the smallest floating point values?

Tags: c++

A simple [experiment](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/221e39981be6f2ca) using `to_string` with the minimum floating point values, results in `0.0000` for both `float` and `double` types:

```cpp
std::to_string(std::numeric_limits<float>::min());
std::to_string(std::numeric_limits<double>::min());
```

The correct answer would be, e.g. `1.17549e-38` for the float type. Is this a known limitation of `std::to_string` or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way around this, so that I can get the correct result?

Comment: Very useful note: [`std::to_string` provides results in line with the results of `sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: It is very strange to me that `std::to_string(double)` is the same as `sprintf("%f")`. I would have expected either `"%.17g"` (if we want to ensure no precision loss) or `"%.15g"` (if we target human readability).

Comment: consider using `std::to_chars` ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars))...

Comment: @C.M. Yes, `to_chars` and `from_chars` were my initial though due to the efficiency but got even more unexpected results. Are you using them with a current library release? what version has a stable implementation?

Comment: @prapin The way I see it is `to_string` is intended to be really easy to use (that means it's got to be really stupid and inflexible) with the default behaviour catching the widest number of conventional use cases to minimize surprise. Whether they truly captured the most common use cases, I can't say, but I'd expect no scientific notation and 6 decimal places to be a pretty decent assumption.

Comment: If you want to test want to stress-test the code with the *smallest* value, you might consider: [`std::numeric_limits<>::denorm_min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/denorm_min)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use oss instead of `std::to_string` in C++. Main reason is to_string makes prediction using `std::fixed` parameter.

Simply your code needs to look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    //std::cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::min() << std::endl;
    //std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::min() << std::endl;
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
    std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
    out << std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do people just know what "oss" is supposed to mean? It seems like a very unnecessary abbreviation to put in the answer.  I had to look at the code to guess at your meaning.

Comment: @sweenish what, you've never heard of the Office of Strategic Services?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I usually don't use string streams because it's an order of magnitude slower to do the conversion this way. Can be optimized if you hide the conversion in a function that has a `thread_local` string stream that is re-used every time. In both (function or local variable) cases one has to clear their streams before using them again, your code has an error and will end up printing both values the second time https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/775834d48d25511e

Comment: @sewwnish oss mean `output string stream`. for the error part I relly dont know. you my need just out.clear() ???

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that it doesn't mean Open Source Software?